# Find all pages that redirect to the existing/instanciated Wikipedia page

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Given a page in wikipedia, how to find/retrieve (using either Wikipedia or Wikimedia) all the name of the pages that will redirect to this page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MW v1.24 or later you may use [prop=redirects](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Redirects).

Example:
All redirects of English Wikipedia's main page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=redirects